# Updating table with joining id in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I’m trying to update a table that is joined with another one to update the right record. 
Here is my command so far:

```
UPDATE
  links l
SET
  l.l_id = `[value-1]`,
  l.l_facebook = `[value-2]`,
  l.l_youtube = `[value-3]`,
  l.l_twitter = `[value-4]`,
  l.l_googleplus = `[value-5]`,
  l.l_rss = `[value-6]`,
  l.l_homepage = `[value-7]`,
  l.l_freigegeben = `[value-8]`
JOIN
  sponsering ON l.l_id = sponsering.links_l_id
WHERE
  sponsering.s_userID = 2
```

Trying to run the command in phpmyadmin gives me the following error message:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'JOIN   sponsering ON l.l_id = sponsering.links_l_id WHERE
>   sponsering.s_user' at line 12

I need to join the table `sponsering` because this gives me the correct record in the links table. 
How can I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do an UPDATE statement with JOIN in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql)

Comment: You seem to be mixing SQL Server and MySQL syntax.

Comment: I don't know the answer for this but by l_faceook you probably mean l_facebook ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE
  links l,
  sponsering s
SET
  l.l_faceook = `[value-2]`,
  l.l_youtube = `[value-3]`,
  l.l_twitter = `[value-4]`,
  l.l_googleplus = `[value-5]`,
  l.l_rss = `[value-6]`,
  l.l_homepage = `[value-7]`,
  l.l_freigegeben = `[value-8]`
WHERE
  l.l_id = s.links_l_id AND
  sponsering.s_userID = 2
```

Comment: gives me the following message: 1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`webuser462_dev`.`sponsering`, CONSTRAINT `fk_sponsering_links1` FOREIGN KEY (`links_l_id`) REFERENCES `links` (`l_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Comment: Don't set `l.l_id = [value-1]`. I changed my query. The problem is in records pointing to this `id` from another table(s). So you can't touch them as it can violate the consistency.

Comment: Great man! I simply forget that I never wanted to change the `l_id` ... sorry about that and thanks for your fast answer! Approved.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, the `join` is part of the `update` statement itself.  There is no separate `from`:

```
UPDATE links l JOIN
       sponsering s
       ON l.l_id = s.links_l_id
    SET
      l.l_id = `[value-1]`,
      l.l_faceook = `[value-2]`,
      l.l_youtube = `[value-3]`,
      l.l_twitter = `[value-4]`,
      l.l_googleplus = `[value-5]`,
      l.l_rss = `[value-6]`,
      l.l_homepage = `[value-7]`,
      l.l_freigegeben = `[value-8]`
    WHERE s.s_userID = 2;
```

Some other databases use a `FROM` clause for the same purpose.

Comment: give me the following error message: 1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (webuser462_dev.sponsering, CONSTRAINT fk_sponsering_links1 FOREIGN KEY (links_l_id) REFERENCES links (l_id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Comment: @Hack4Life . . . That would be an entirely different problem from the syntax error, because that error occurs when it is running.  You need to be sure that the data is correct, and it seems like your `update` is violating a foreign key constraint.